# How do I throw a ball on particular angle?

Tags: android

I want to create a game like "Angry Bird". I want to throw a ball from a destination to a target on a parabolic curve. I have the angle-selection part implemented but now I need to throw a ball from this angle.

```
if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        emX = (int) event.getX();
        emY = (int) event.getY();
        if (emX < h / 2 && emY < w / 2) {

            if (spX != emX || spY != emY) {
                olX = spX;
                olY = spY;
                spX = (int) event.getX();
                spY = (int) event.getY();
                int kx = spX - olX;
                int ky = spY - olY;

                if (Math.abs(kx) > Math.abs(ky)) {
                    if (kx < 0 && angle > 0) {
                        angle -= 1;
                    } else if (angle < 90) {
                        angle += 1;
                        int temp = angle;
                        temp++;
                        System.out.println("Temp is= " + temp);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (ky < 0 && angle > 0) {
                        angle -= 1;
                    } else if (angle < 90) {
                        angle += 1;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

How can I throw on object using the angle selected from the above method?

Comment: I edited your question, but am not completely sure if I understood everything right, especially the part regarding the angle selection. Please verify. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally: What exactly is your concrete question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to throw an object from angle which is selected by user. actually i have wrote above code for angle but now if you can provide me any method or class which can be use to jump or throw an object in parabolic curve..

Comment: You could clarify your question with an image. BYW, If you need some throwing like angrybird , you can use [Projectile Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

Answer (score 0):

By throwing, i think you want some force added.
Do this:
Let the angle u want to throw be 60degree.
And the force to be applied be 2Newton
So, by using trignometric identities, u could do this:

Vector2 force = new Vector2(2 * sin(60), 2 * cos(60));

Apply the force to ur body. (Most libraries take vector as force).
(Also, u might want to convert it into your library)

Hope it helps :)